# Systemd - Python script Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE

Tags: python, ubuntu, service, systemd, autorun

Hi everyone the situation is the following:
I am connetected to an ubuntu-based EC2 machine of AWS ( and I am currently working on Ubuntu 18.04).
I can manage files inside the machine and run scripts from terminal but I want the machine to run a script even when I am not connected. So I thought about a service.

Using systemd I located this file on /lib/systemd/system :

> [Unit] Description=Test Service After=network.target 
> Conflicts=getty@tty1.service
>
> [Service] Type=simple ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3  /home/ubuntu/GreenHouse/Catalog/Catalog_REST.py 
> StandardInput=tty-force
>
> [Install] WantedBy=multi-user.target

I started the service,ut when I check the status:

```
 sudo systemctl status CATALOG_REST-py.service
```

I receive this error:

> ● CATALOG_REST-py.service - Test Service    Loaded: loaded
> (/lib/systemd/system/CATALOG_REST-py.service; enabled; vendor preset:
> enabled)    Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2021-08-22
> 16:54:13 UTC; 1s ago   Process: 23968 ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3
> /home/GreenHouse/Catalog/Catalog_REST.py (code=exited,
> status=1/FAILURE)  Main PID: 23968 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
>
> Aug 22 16:54:13 ip-172-31-13-245 systemd[1]: Started Test Service. Aug
> 22 16:54:13 ip-172-31-13-245 systemd[1]: CATALOG_REST-py.service: Main
> process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAIL Aug 22 16:54:13
> ip-172-31-13-245 systemd[1]: CATALOG_REST-py.service: Failed with
> result 'exit-code'.

I want to say that if I run in terminal `python3 /home/GreenHouse/Catalog/Catalog_REST.py` , it works.

Do you know some ways to obtain a **better explanation of the error**?

Answer (score 1):

As better described in [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/665768/systemd-python-script-main-process-exited-code-exited-status-1-failure), the issue may be related to the runtime environment.

In that case, a possible quick solution in my experience is to replace your service with the following one (it only differs for the `ExecStart` line):

```
[Unit] 
Description=Test Service After=network.target
Conflicts=getty@tty1.service

[Service] 
Type=simple 
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c "/usr/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/GreenHouse/Catalog/Catalog_REST.py"
StandardInput=tty-force

[Install] 
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then reload the *systemd manager configuration* and restart your service:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart CATALOG_REST-py.service
```

Comment: Thank you for you interest. 
At the end, I changed the strategy: 
I decided to use tmux sessions in order to run different codes simultaneously, even when I wasn't connected.
It worked at the end, even if it was quite computationally heavy. In fact, the EC2 used to crash when many tmux sessions were on.  However, I don't know if it actually depends on tmux and if  the results would have been the same with a different approach. 
Anyway, I finished the university project and tmux was a useful and quick solution!

Comment: That did not work for me. After reboot, process is still killed. When starting the process manually with "systemctl start" after boot, all fine. Strange.